# No response has been set

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-api-nodejs-client, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using the ***dialogflow agent*** and trying to send a response to the user.
Here is my code:

```
app.intent('Answer6', (conv) => {
    const ans = conv.parameters.any;
        senddata[8] = qstion[8] + ans;
        conv.close('Thank you');
    
});
```

After this intent, I am getting this error:

> Error: No response has been set.

Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler? at DialogflowConversation.response

Comment: Can you post your entire fulfillment function as code here? This doesn't read like I would expect your function to read

Comment: This is the full code. The error is coming from here itself. It was working fine suddenly this error popped up.

Comment: You are missing the whole bracket of code that actually handles initialising your application. For example I would expect some imports, at the top, and some equivalent to `exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using async functions, and it doesn't look like you are, this is usually an indication that your function crashed while running. You may wish to check the logs of where the function is running (Cloud Functions, for example) and see what other errors are being generated.

Comment: This is very good advice. Checking the underlying logs for anything else going wrong (as DF webhook status errors are particularly unhelpful) is my first port of call.

Comment: Alriight. Thanks